# How to alternate the position of TextView in Android from adapter of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

trying to build a chat bot, but how to alternate the `TextView` in `RecyclerView`'s adapter. See the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see, all the responses are currently aligned to the start, I'd like to move the reply from one person to the other side from the adapter of the `RecyclerView`. Here is the code to the adapter:

**CustomAdapter.class**

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.FeedsViewHolder>
{



    DataHolder d1 = new DataHolder();

    public  class FeedsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView chat;
        private Typeface face;

        FeedsViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            chat = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
            face = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            chat.setTypeface(face);


        }



    }

    private static class DataHolder
    {
        List<Text> feeds;

    }



    CustomAdapter(List<Text> feeds)
    {
        this.d1.feeds = feeds;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    @Override
    public FeedsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_message, viewGroup, false);
        FeedsViewHolder pvh = new FeedsViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedsViewHolder feedViewHolder, int i)
    {
        if(d1.feeds.get(i).isMachineOrHuman())
        {
            feedViewHolder.chat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user);
            feedViewHolder.chat.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
        }

        else
            feedViewHolder.chat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ais);


        feedViewHolder.chat.setText(d1.feeds.get(i).getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {

        if(d1.feeds!=null)
        {
            return d1.feeds.size();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }



}
```

**chat_message.xml**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/chatMessage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Now, I made an alternative solution, that is by keeping two `TextView`s in `chat_message.xml` and changing the visibility settings of the unused `TextView` . But what I am looking for is whether is it possible to do it with a single `TextView`. Also, the background of the `TextView` is a `9-patch-image` , which is assigned as a background resource from the adapter, so when I move the `TextView` it shouldn't also spoil the background. Any thoughts would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: 1. TextView in RelativeLayout with width match parent, 2. set align parent right layout parameter instead TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END... *so when I move the TextView it shouldn't also spoil the background.* ... huh??

Comment: You can wrap your TextView in a Layout that supports gravity(e.g. LinearLayout) and use Gravity.START and Gravity.END(or layout_gravity in XML)

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedsViewHolder feedViewHolder, int i)
    {
        if(d1.feeds.get(i).isMachineOrHuman())
        {
            feedViewHolder.chat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user);
            **feedViewHolder.chat.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);** // *Sent Message*
            feedViewHolder.chat.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
        }

        else {
            feedViewHolder.chat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ais);
          **feedViewHolder.chat.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);** // *Receive Message*
            feedViewHolder.chat.setText(d1.feeds.get(i).getMessage());

    }
```

Create A child layout under the parent layout for **The bubble(9-patch)** and set the **Gravity** approrpriately as the TEXT(Message).

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/message_bubble"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:minHeight="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Put your message"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorLink="@color/black"
        android:textSize="?attr/TextSizeBody"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]